# What's the best way to build a function that would enrich an object in Typscript

Tags: typescript

I need to enrich data that I'm getting from the backend, before I show it on the frontend and I'm not sure how to do that well in Typescript.

My idea is, I have an array of object, that contain each and ID, and I want to enrich each object by grabbing data from another array. I just don't know how to make it so it's efficient.

My initial object :

```
data = [{id:1, done:false}, {id:2, done:true}]
```

My function that will enrich my object :

```
function enrich(data){
     foreach data ...
}
```

And my Storage for enriched data :

```
storage = [{id: 1, title: "this will be added", name: "this will be added too"}, {id:2, title="yes add me too to object who has id=2", name="enriched"}]
```

And of course the result of passing data into my enricher function would be :

```
data = [{id:1, done:false, title: "this will be added", name: "this will be added too"}, {id:2, done:true, title="yes add me too to object who has id=2", name="enriched"}]
```

Any help appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: I would totally not add anything, your data is complete. You should not append UI details there, as you can derive UI by `done` property, so what I would suggest is just create function which will take take `bool` and return `string`, and use it in your UI like `(done: boolean) => done ? "yes done" : "not done yet"`

If you can compute this state from another you don't need to keep it.`

Comment: Do you actually want to mutate your `data` array or would producing a new array with merged data be acceptable?  What do you want to see if `storage` doesn't have an appropriate entry?  What do you mean by "efficient" here?  The obvious implementation is O(n^2) but that is probably fine unless you have an enormous amount of data; otherwise you'd want to refactor so that either your data or your storage or both is a dictionary with the id as the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the `enrich` function like this:

```js
var storage = [{id: 1, title: "this will be added", name: "this will be added too"}, 
               {id:2, title: "yes add me too to object who has id=2", name: "enriched"}];

var data = [{id:1, done:false}, {id:2, done:true}];

function enrich(data){
  for (var d of data) {
    var item = storage.find(x => x.id === d.id);
    
    d.title = item.title;
    d.name = item.name;
  }
}

enrich(data);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, we are calling a function that will return a new array containing the result you are looking for.

NOTE: We are not mutating any data ; in opposition to the working answer of @Tân

```js
const storage = [{
  id: 1,
  title: 'this will be added',
  name: 'this will be added too',
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'yes add me too to object who has id=2',
  name: 'enriched',
}];

/**
 * Enrich the data looking at the storage
 */
function enrich(toEnrich) {
  // Look for the data on the storage for each data in the toEnrich array
  // Map will create a new array based on the toEnrich data
  // Every data we return here will be a part of the new array
  return toEnrich.map(x => ({
    // Build a new object
    
    // We copy all the keys from the toEnrich array
    ...x,

    // We look for the data in storage and copy it into the new object
    // The || is here to prevent the fact we do not find the appropriate data
    // in storage array
    ...(storage.find(y => y.id === x.id) || {}),
  }));
}

console.log(enrich([{
  id: 1,
  done: false,
}, {
  id: 2,
  done: true,
}, {
  id: 3,
  done: true,
}]));
```